# Python while looping over list but not finding value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a while loop that is looping over a list trying to find the number 1. I have the code below and it loops over "almost" all the list but it does not find the index for value 1

```
numbers = [24, 10, 92, 28, 71, 1, 80, 70]
counter = 0
number_to_find = 1

def my_loop():
    global counter
    while counter > 6: #Also not sure while 7 doesn't work, says out of range?
        if numbers[counter] == number_to_find:
            print "Number found at position", counter 
    
    else:
        print "Counter not found in position" , counter
        counter = counter + 1
        my_loop()


print my_loop()
```

Comment: Might I ask why you are using a while loop and recursion instead of a simple for-loop?

Comment: ...and why you're using global variables?

Comment: ...or `numbers.index(1)`?

Comment: You never break out of your while loop so the `else` clause will always be executed which means this never terminates (except when you reach max recursion depth)

Comment: @glibdud the use of global variables is not really an issue here IMO. It's clearly beginner code, so a little early to start worrying about globals in general. A more nuanced point is that Python doesn't actually have _globals_ in the same sense as many other scripting languages. Python has module-level globals, which are still neatly namespaced. It's not nearly as "bad" a thing.

Comment: I believe you have indentation and condition check issues -  see fixed code below.

Comment: It might help all these answers if you could actually propose what you wanted the output to look like. It's not entirely clear given the non-working code example.

Answer (score 9):

This is a very confusing bit of code.

1. You `print` the output, but the function does not return anything. (It also prints things, but it does not return anything.)
2. The function has a `while` loop and also recurs upon itself. (There are some cases where this is appropriate, but this is not one of them.)
3. `counter` is initially 0, but your first check is if `counter > 6`. 0 is not greater than six. (This is not technically wrong, but very confusing.)
4. The value `1` is at index 5. Why are you looking for 6?
5. Once you have reached the desired index, you do not terminate the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve what you're looking for using the following piece of code:

```
numbers = [24, 10, 92, 28, 71, 1, 80, 1, 70]
number_to_find = 1

for i,j in enumerate(numbers):
    if j == number_to_find:
        print i, "=>", j

# Output
>>> 5 => 1
>>> 7 => 1
```

If your `numbers` doesn't contains repeated numbers, you can use the following piece of code, as sugested by kojiro:

```
numbers = [24, 10, 92, 28, 71, 1, 80, 70]
number_to_find = 1

print numbers.index(number_to_find)

# Output
>>> 5
```

But if your code contains repeated chars, it'll show only the first ocurrence:

```
numbers = [24, 10, 92, 28, 71, 1, 80, 1, 70]
number_to_find = 1

print numbers.index(number_to_find)

# Output
>>> 5
```

Comment: `print numbers.index(1)`? I think the point is not merely to solve the problem here, since Python already does that for you.

Comment: Only if you know the right commands... Your code is new stuff to me, thanks!

Comment: If you run your code using `numbers=[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 10, 1]`, your code only show's the index of the first ocurring "1".

Answer (score 2):

> `while counter > 6:`

If `counter` is greater than 6, it must be 7 or greater. If you're looping `while counter > 7`, you're indexing out of the range of the size of the list (which is indexed from 0 to 7).

> `global counter`

Don't do this. You shouldn't use globals. [There are good reasons](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)

> def my_loop():
>       ...
>           my_loop()

You don't need recursion for this. This is quite simple with just a for loop (in fact, you can do it without that).

I'll post a few ways to solve this problem:

## enumerate

```
def find_needle(needle, haystack):
    for idx, item in enumerate(haystack):
        if needle == item:
            return idx
    return None
```

## index

```
 def find_needle(needle, haystack):
     return haystack.index(needle)
```

These two implementations don't do *exactly* the same thing - the first will return `None` if `needle` isn't found in `haystack`, where the second will throw a `ValueError`. I think the former is more forgiving, but it's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

So there are many ways to do this, iteratively and recursively but to take the OP's code as is and what I think they were attempting.

Note: it is generally considered bad practice to use global variables, you should pass the list of `numbers` and the number to `find` to the function.

Note: your while loop is effectively implementing a for loop - `for counter in range(len(numbers)):` would provide the same result

```
numbers = [24, 10, 92, 28, 71, 1, 80, 70]
number_to_find = 1

def my_loop():
    counter = 0
    while counter < len(numbers):
        if numbers[counter] == number_to_find:
            print "Number found at position", counter 
        else:
            print "Counter not found in position" , counter
        counter = counter + 1

my_loop()
```

Output:

```
Counter not found in position 0
Counter not found in position 1
Counter not found in position 2
Counter not found in position 3
Counter not found in position 4
Number found at position 5
Counter not found in position 6
Counter not found in position 7
```

Doing the same thing with a `for` loop:

```
for counter in range(len(numbers)):
    if numbers[counter] == number_to_find:
        print "Number found at position", counter 
    else:
        print "Counter not found in position" , counter
```

Would output the same.
However, perhaps a more idiomatic approach for Python would be to use `enumerate`:

```
for counter, number in enumerate(numbers):
    if number == number_to_find:
        print "Number found at position", counter 
    else:
        print "Counter not found in position" , counter
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for, just how to make my code work without rewriting in to be the most elegant, shortest possible. Although I appreciate all the inputs this has made the most sense to me, since its where I am right now. I lot of the answers are over my head.

Comment: Glad that helped. I've added the equivalent `for` loop approach.

Answer (score 0):

To find first occurence use  `numbers.index(x)` where `x` is the number you are searching or for all of them `indices = [idx for idx, number in enumerate(numbers) if elem_list == x]`

Comment: this doesn't really answer the OP's question -- he was asking to find what the bug in his code is (you seem to opine that the whole code is one big bug :-)

Comment: You could argue, that it is.  Reinventing the wheel (although maybe for learning purposes)  is usually a big bug.

Comment: Just trying to help as I can. I started my account several days ago and I might need to read the rules more carefully. You are correct that I have not provided the answer to his question, but just offered a solution for his task

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I think you mean for your `else` block to correspond to the `if`. Right now it's associated with the `while`. Indent the `else` so it's aligned with the `if`, and then indent the three lines after the `else` to align with the `print` after the `if`:

```
        if numbers[counter] == number_to_find:
            print "Number found at position", counter 
        else:
            print "Counter not found in position" , counter
            counter = counter + 1
            my_loop()
```

Once you fix that, your second problem will be that your program will exit immediately because your `while` condition evaluates to `0 > 6`, which is false, so the `if` block will never even run. Minimally you'll want to change the `>` to `<`. At that point, your code will *mostly* work like you expect it to, but consider:

1. The application will go into an infinite loop once it finds the value it's looking for.
2. A `for` loop would be much nicer than a `while` with a counter.
3. You should really avoid using global variables if at all possible (it's very possible here).